# mysql insert handle a lot of values

Tags: php, mysql

is there a clean way of INSERT a lot of field entry values without them having to be in order? similar to how you can do with the UPDATE like below. can INSERT be done in that format?

```
$qstring="UPDATE test SET word = 'something' ,";
$qstring .= " word1 = 'something1',";
...
mysql_query($qstring);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yupp,

```
insert into
    your_table
set
    field_1='Yay!',
    field_2='Mmmbop!',
...
```

Comment: +1 Adding the link to the documentation for reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SET` syntax:

```
insert into my_table set col1='value', col2='value'
```

Or, you can specify column names with a VALUES clause:

```
insert into my_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

Using this later form, the values in the `VALUES` clause must match the order of the values in the column list that precedes the `VALUES` clause.

If you turn on "extended inserts" (it's usually on by default), you can use the latter form to insert multiple rows with a single statement:

```
insert into my_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES 
   ('value1', 'value2', 'value3'), 
   ('row2value1', 'row2value2', 'row2value3'),
   ('row3value1', 'row3value2', 'row3value3')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO test SET word = 'something', word1 = 'something1'
```

Answer (score 1):

yes we can do this also with INSERT

```
$qstring="Insert into test SET";
$qstring .= "word = 'something' ,";
$qstring .= " word1 = 'something1',";
...
mysql_query($qstring);
```